# What is the "database link" icon in Edit User Profile page?

Tags: user-profile, central-administration

[image]

In SP2013 on-premise, in the CA's Edit User Profile page (/_layouts/15/ProfAdminEdit.aspx). Some properties have a "Database link" icon. What is the meaning?

Comment: is below information enough for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can read the line above the form, It is clearly mentioned that

> Use this page to edit this user profile by changing values for the following properties. Properties that are mapped to the external data source will be overwritten the next time user profiles are imported.

The icon indicates that each property of your user profile is **mapped with some external data source**

Comment: It is what my thought at the beginning. The image even named "mapped.gif". However when I checked the properties 1 by 1. e.g. "Web site" or "Display order" they are not mapped to anything. Could you also check your farm? I suspect they are hardcode image.

Comment: External data source can be anything in this context like AD User account or any external application's user account. Some of the fields are not available in SP User Profile so don't worry. This is SharePoint's default form. And about the image, yes it is hard code. SO user can identify that it is mapped somewhere.

Comment: Is this information helps you to understand the use of image in Edit User Profile Page?

Comment: Yes, knowing it is hardcode is helpful. But I wonder "web site" and "display order" can map to what kind of external source.

Comment: I have found about the "website" that if you are mapping LinkedIn account with SharePoint than you can map "Website" column from that account with SharePoint. If you are using custom application than you can map "display order". I am not sure about the use of mapping the display order.

Comment: is my answer helps you to understand the mapping concept for both columns??